# Issue importing an interface from ReactQuill namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript, quill, react-quill

[image]

ReactQuill types file for the reference: https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/blob/v1.3.3/types.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
```

try this. For further reference check here https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#import-the-component

Comment: Thanks! Getting this error in that case: `has no exported member 'ComponentProps'.ts` when using `ReactQuill.ComponentProps`

Comment: can you please share your full code, i want to know how you are trying to use 'ComponentProps'.

Comment: Sorry, here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/edtsech/0189cecb493a82e02758b60ceea2dfca#file-customquill-tsx Errors are listed in the comments.